# Sub-state with multiple parents / route for modal that opens over several states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a abstract `profile` state, which has multiple child states (for different tabs of the profile page), and then I want to have another child state of profile be a modal. I've implemented it something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile/:profileID',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
        abstract:true,
        resolve: {
            user: ...
        }
    })
    .state('profile.circles', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'profilecircles.html',
        controller: 'profilecirclesCtrl',
        resolve: { circle: ... }
    })
    .state('profile.squares', {
        url: '/collections',
        templateUrl: 'profilesquares.html',
        controller: 'profilesquaresCtrl',
        resolve: { squares: ... }
    })
    .state('profile.editprofile', {
        url: '/edit',
        onEnter: ['$window','$modal', function($window, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'editprofile.html',
                controller: 'editProfileCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    user: ...
                }
            }).result.then(function() {
                $window.history.back();
            },function() {
                $window.history.back();
            });
        }]
    })
```

This works great, except for the fact that because editprofile is a sibling of squares and circles, when that state is active and the modal is in view, the squares or circle state is unloaded, and loaded back in again when the modal is closed.

Is there any way to have those states remain active when the profile.editprofile state is active? I'm after something like `state..editprofile`.

Comment: Were any answers here helpful for you?

Answer (score 3):

As there is currently no ideal solution, I have come up with a reasonably elegant solution. My code is generalized, easy to understand and commented so that it should be easy to adapt to any project.

See the comments in the code for the most significant points.

### [Live Demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKRYc73JXgFdI3XjMlYw?p=preview)

#### Sample States

```
$stateProvider

// modal will open over this state from any substate
.state('foo', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/:fooProp',
  templateUrl: 'foo.html',
  controller: 'FooController'
})
.state('foo.main', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'foo-main.html',
  controller: 'FooMainController'
})
.state('foo.bar', {
  url: '/bars/:barId',
  templateUrl: 'foo-bar.html',
  controller: 'FooBarController'
})

// append /modal route to each `foo` substate
.state('foo.main.modal', getModalState())
.state('foo.bar.modal', getModalState())

;

function getModalState() {
  return {
    url: '/modal',
    onEnter: [
      '$modal',
      '$state',
      function($modal, $state) {
        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'foo-modal.html',
          controller: 'FooModalController'
        }).result.finally(function() {
          // go to parent state - the current `foo` substate
          $state.go('^');
        });
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.goToModalState = function() {
  // go to this state's `modal` state
  $state.go($state.current.name+'.modal');
};
```

#### View

```
<a ng-click="goToModalState()">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: What about using sibling states for the last part of your approach [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#to). So it would go something like `<a ui-sref=".modal">Open Modal</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Well unless you want ditch the modal implementation I would suggest then having 2 views in `profile.html` one for `editprofile.html` and other for `profilecircles.html` or `profilesquares.html`, something like following:

```
// profile.html
...
<div class="" ui-view="edit" autoscroll="false"></div>
<div class="" ui-view="content" autoscroll="false"></div>
...

// state config
$stateProvider
.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile/:profileID',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    abstract:true,
    resolve: {
        user: ...
    }
})
.state('profile.circles', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        edit@: {
            templateUrl: 'editprofile.html',
            controller: 'editProfileCtrl'
        },
        content@: {
            templateUrl: 'profilecircles.html',
            controller: 'profilecirclesCtrl'
        }
    }
    resolve: { circle: ... }
})
.state('profile.squares', {
    url: '/collections',
    views: {
        edit@: {
            templateUrl: 'editprofile.html',
            controller: 'editProfileCtrl'
        },
        content@: {
            templateUrl: 'profilesquares.html',
            controller: 'profilesquaresCtrl'
        }
    }
    resolve: { squares: ... }
})
```

And then the hard part for actually showing/hiding the edit profile view. But that can be done with some toggle button or after action is validated in controller.

Comment: So I can't have a state for the edit profile? I'm *quite* happy with how I can use onEnter to open a modal at a specific route and would love to continue that...

Comment: Well the other solution I could think of is to have 2 children states for squares and circles `profile.squares.editprofile` and `profile.circles.editprofile` as then you would not lose the context of parent state which is the problem for you. Or accept parameter on `profile` state and show modal via logic in `ProfileCtrl` but not sure if latter will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

The point of ui-router is that the states nesting matches the url nesting. What that means is that in your case if you have:

```
profile.circles with a url: /profile/123
profiles.squares with a url: /profile/123/collections
profiles.edit with a url: /profile/123/edit
```

You can't expect to have profile.squares and profiles.edit active at the same time since they are two completely different urls. However It is possible to have:

```
profiles.circles.editprofile with a url: /profile/123/edit
```

That will keep profiles.circles active during your modal since it's a parent state. 
But in the case of profiles.squares, if you want to have a state representing editprofile you would need something like:

```
profiles.squares.editprofile with a url: /profile/123/collection/edit
```

Unfortunately there is no other way around it if you want to keep edit as a state.

Comment: But this isn't actually a problem, you could use the same template and the same controller for it so your logic doesn't need to be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can designate your tab states `sticky: true` by using [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home). Sticky states are preserved when navigating to a sibling and are especially useful for tabs.

To use it, you'll have to create **one named view for each sticky state** (you can hide inactive ones however, see below).

The [API page](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) describes the necessary steps:

1. Mark a state with `sticky: true`
2. Declare a named view on the state which will target a named ui-view in the parent state's template, e.g. `views: { bar: { /* bar named-view definition */ } }`
3. Add the named ui-view to the parent state's template, e.g. `<div ui-view="bar" />`
4. Optionally, hide the named ui-view when the state is not activated, e.g. `<div ui-view="bar" ng-show="$state.includes("foo.bar") />`